# why `pdb` states something unrelated and misleading?

Tags: python

My Python script reports where it goes wrong ("line 122" in myscript.py), when I run it in a shell:

```
$ toc2others.py -i toc -p pg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/myscript.py", line 122, in <module>
    p = re.match(keywords[index+1][0], inlines[n+1], re.IGNORECASE)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It is because `keywords[index+1]` goes out of the index range of `keywords`.

When I run it under `pdb`, however, it doesn't report where it goes wrong, but says something unrelated (error is reported to take place at `import re`).

```
$ pdb ~/myscript.py -i toc -p pg
> /myscript.py(3)<module>()
-> import re
(Pdb) c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1314, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 387, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/myscript.py", line 3, in <module>
    import re
IndexError: list index out of range
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
```

I wonder why `pdb` states something unrelated and misleading?

Can `pdb` state where it actually goes wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, actually.
See issues:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue16482
- http://bugs.python.org/issue17277

This only happens if exception is thrown on module-level of executed file, i.e. not inside any function. So if you just put your code in a `main()` function, this will fix it. Or you can use ipython, which is much more fun for debugging:

```
ipython ~/myscript.py --pdb -- -i toc -p pg
```

This will run the script and only stop if there's an error, and it also does not suffer from the above bug.